# Problem displaying my mobile first design

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, responsive-design

I'm not sure what the heck is going wrong here. Whenever I preview my site on a renderer like this, [example](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//wp19.knowgreaterpartnership.com&w=360&h=640&a=39&s=1), my site displays differently from an actual phone display. This is making it very difficult to test and adapt for other screen sizes.

I'm doing a mobile-first layout, but everything was working just fine until chrome started acting up (something my department isn't allowed to fix, so that's not an option) which is why I'm resorting to these types of sites. Also, the only other browsers I'm permitted to use are IE and Edge.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page is missing a viewport meta tag in the `<head>`

Adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` should make the page render as expected on mobile devices.

Comment: thanks that made it display on my device the same. Now it's all jacked up in both places! hahaha.

Comment: Jeff, if Heather's answer was spot on please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @cabrerahector, I was planning on it. I had to wait 6 minutes apparently to mark it as such and then got sidetracked.